# Can't save a typed array in ChromeOS app correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, file, blob

I'm creating an app for chromeOS.. problem is, when I try to save a typed array, it becomes complete nonsense.

For example, here's a PNG file opened in HexReader:
[check it out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wumIL.png)

Now, I try to save the same image using this code:

```
var data = new Uint8Array([0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0D, 0x49, 0x48, 0x44, 0x52, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x08, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x8D, 0x32, 0xCF, 0xBD, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x13, 0x49, 0x44, 0x41, 0x54, 0x78, 0xDA, 0x63, 0x60, 0x60, 0x60, 0xF8, 0x4F, 0x24, 0x1E, 0x55, 0x48, 0x4F, 0x85, 0x00, 0x34, 0xBD, 0x63, 0x9D, 0x45, 0xBF, 0x95, 0x85, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x49, 0x45, 0x4E, 0x44, 0xAE, 0x42, 0x60, 0x82]);

var blob = new Blob( data, {type:'application/octect-binary'} );

// Allow saving of our file
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry( {type:"saveFile"}, function (a)
{
    a.createWriter( function (b)
    {
        b.write( blob );
    });
});
```

But then guess what? I open it and it doesn't open as a PNG, when I check it in Hex Reader, [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7twY.png)

So question is, what, how, when, why? FML lmao ^.^'
Been trying to save png for such a long time... one day i swear..

Comment: I'm not sure Uint8Array supports a constructor that takes a normal array. From the documentation I can only see (length), (typedArray), (object), (buffer [, byteOffset [, length]]).

Comment: I'm no javascript expert, but as far as I knew using new Uint8Array( [array] ) has always worked for me =)

Comment: Alright, then it will most likely use the (object) constructor, which is the same as calling Uint8Array.from().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Blob` constructor is defined as `new Blob( array, options )` where `array` is documented as

> `array` is an `Array` of `ArrayBuffer`, `ArrayBufferView`, `Blob`, `DOMString` objects, or a > mix of any of such objects, that will be put inside the Blob.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob

In your example you're passing the `Uint8Array` directly into the blob, which suprisingly doesn't give an error, but it does place the wrong data into the `Blob`.

**Try this**

```
var data = new Uint8Array([0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0D, 0x49, 0x48, 0x44, 0x52, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x08, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x8D, 0x32, 0xCF, 0xBD, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x13, 0x49, 0x44, 0x41, 0x54, 0x78, 0xDA, 0x63, 0x60, 0x60, 0x60, 0xF8, 0x4F, 0x24, 0x1E, 0x55, 0x48, 0x4F, 0x85, 0x00, 0x34, 0xBD, 0x63, 0x9D, 0x45, 0xBF, 0x95, 0x85, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x49, 0x45, 0x4E, 0x44, 0xAE, 0x42, 0x60, 0x82]);

var blob = new Blob( [data], {type:'application/octect-binary'} );

// Allow saving of our file
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry( {type:"saveFile"}, function (a)
{
    a.createWriter( function (b)
    {
        b.write( blob );
    });
});
```